# Как загрузить файл на сервер golang?

Tags: javascript, golang, fileupload, upload

Как загружать файлы на сервер *golang*?
Можете, пожалуйста, привести пример со стороны *go* и *JavaScript*?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/golang-book/bootcamp-examples/blob/master/week2/day3/file-upload-example/main.go

```
package main


    import (

      "net/http"
      "io"
      "os"
      "path/filepath"
      "fmt"
    )
    func main() {

      fmt.Println("TEMP DIR:", os.TempDir())
      http.ListenAndServe(":9000", http.HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        if req.Method == "POST" {
          src, hdr, err := req.FormFile("my-file")
          if err != nil {
            http.Error(res, err.Error(), 500)
            return
          }
          defer src.Close()

          dst, err := os.Create(filepath.Join(os.TempDir(), hdr.Filename))
          if err != nil {
            http.Error(res, err.Error(), 500)
            return
          }
          defer dst.Close()

          io.Copy(dst, src)
        }

        res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
        io.WriteString(res, `
          <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="my-file">
            <input type="submit">
          </form>
          `)
        }))
    }
```