# Как отправить файл на сервер golang ajax-ом?

Tags: ajax, golang, fileupload, upload, jquery-file-upload

Подскажите как отправить файл на сервер golang ajax-ом?
Подобный пример здесь [Как загрузить файл на сервер golang?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568315/) , но тут происходит перезагрузка страницы, а если пытаюсь ajax-ом загрузить, то сервер go не могу настроить,что б он принял файл.
Подскажите пожалуйста-как быть?

Answer (score 1):

```
//подключаем Jquery
<form method="POST" id="FormUpload" action="/api/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="File" name="my-file">
        <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
$("form#FormUpload").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/upload',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(returndata) {
                alert(returndata);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });</script>
```

Golang

```
func Upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("my-file") 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()


    f, err := os.OpenFile(handler.Filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    io.Copy(f, file)
}
```